# From Euro currency format to USD currency format in PHP

Tags: php, number-formatting, currency-formatting, euro

How can I convert Euor currency format to USD currency format. I just want to format the numbers and no conversion rate is included here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use any form of currency formatting internally in your script: maintain values as simple floats inside your scripts, and only format them when actually displaying them to a user.... then you never need to convert from one formatted string to another

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for your reply. Actually I have lot of currency values in different fromat mostly Euro, Canadian Dollars and British Pound and my project requirement is to convert all of them simply in floats in a database table.

Comment: Are these string values that simply include a currency code? Or do some use `,` as a decimal separator instead of `.`, a space as a thousands separator instead of `,`, etc?

Comment: yes `,` as a decimal separator and a space as thousands separator and no currency code is involved.

Comment: Tricky because of the ambiguity of `,` which sometimes needs to be removed and sometimes needs to be converted to a decimal point.... if you know the locale/currency for any value, you may be able to use PHP's [international currency formatter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) [parseCurrency()](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) method

Comment: you can use number_format("1000000",2,",","."); php number_format function while display data.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. It is [parse](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php) function of [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'fr_FR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$num = "1 234,56";
echo $fmt->parse($num)."\n";
```

It is working fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [`NumberFormatter`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class can represent different kinds of number formatting. It has a [`parseCurrency()`](https://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) method to parse strings with currency values.

With this you should be able to create parsers for the different number formats you have to handle.

Comment: `$fmt = new NumberFormatter( "de_DE", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
$number = "0,007";
$curr = "USD";
echo "We have ".$fmt->parseCurrency($number, $curr)." in $curr\n";` returns me `We have  in USD` 

any idea how can this work?