# how to convert php string to float keeping the decimal values

Tags: php

I have a string with the price '23,99', how do I convert this to float with php?

```php
$price = '23,99';
$price_float = floatval($price);
echo $price_float;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182561/from-euro-currency-format-to-usd-currency-format-in-php See [`NumberFormatter` document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)

Answer (score 3):

As you already discovered, you can replace the `,` with a `.`. There is another way which might be useful too. Using the [NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php), you can format the number in different ways. Based on a *locale* as well as using different formatters such as *currency*, *percent* or *scientific*. See the docs for all options. In you case, using the locale for Portugal, you could use:

```
$price = '23,99';
$numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter("pt-PT", \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
echo $numberFormatter->parse($price); // Wil output the float 23.99
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, since I didn't find any php solution, and assuming `","` is the separator, I made this function to overcome it

```php
 function floatdec($a){
   $b = explode(',',$a);
   return floatval($b[0]) + floatval($b[1])/100;
 }

 $price = '23,99';
 echo floatdec($price).'<br>';
 echo gettype(floatdec($price));
```

A few hours later...  I found out that adding 0 (i.e. `+ 0`) to a string makes it an integer or double, the string only needs to be with the decimal point.

```php
function floatdec($a){
    return str_replace(",",".",$a) + 0;
}
```

Comment: You should look into typecasting. If you always want to return a float use `return (float) str_replace(",",".",$a);`